# STORE KIT - Cannot connect to iTunes Store

Tags: iphone, storekit

this is my situation:

1. I have an app of which i want to add in app purchase. I created an update version of the app. I uploaded a binary and rejected.
2. On the provisioning portal i created an app-id with unique id ( not wildchard * ) like: com.mycompanyname.myappintheoryblablabla
3. I created a new provisioning profile based on the above app-id
4. i installed via xcode the prov profile on the development device and set in the app this profile in the field "code signing identity"
5. On itunes connect i created 2 item for the in app purchase and set ad "clear for sale"
6. in the application code i implemened the basic calls taken from the Apple sample

what i am getting is ( as stated in the subject ) CANNOT CONNECT TO ITUNES STORE.

Any clue?
Can anyone help me?

Regards

Comment: the answer is here [cannot connect to itunes answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2359739/iphone-store-kit-cannot-connect-to-itunes-store)

Comment: possible duplicate of [iPhone In-App Purchase Store Kit error -1003 "Cannot connect to iTunes Store"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1717700/iphone-in-app-purchase-store-kit-error-1003-cannot-connect-to-itunes-store)

Comment: possible duplicate of [iPhone Store Kit "Cannot connect to iTunes Store"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2359739/iphone-store-kit-cannot-connect-to-itunes-store)

Answer (score 0):

This is what I got from an expert in the field:

> FAQ 6 of Tech Note 2259 - provides a comprehensive list of the known reasons for the product preflight failure (where all of the items in an SKProductRequest are returned in the invalidProductsIdentifiers array.
>
> Here is FAQ 6
>
> Why are my product identifiers being returned in the invalidProductIdentifiers array?
>   Your product identifiers may be returned in the invalidProductIdentifiers array for one or more of the following reasons:
>
> You did not complete all the financial requirements (see the "Contracts, Tax, and Banking Information" section of this document).
>   You did not use an explicit App ID.
>   You did not use the Provisioning Profile associated with your explicit App ID.
>   You did not use the correct product identifier in your code. See Technical Q&A, QA1329, 'In App Purchase Product Identifiers' for more information about product identifiers.
>   You did not clear your In App Purchase products for sale in iTunes Connect.
>   You might have modified your products, but these changes are not yet available to all the App Store servers.
>   If you or App Review rejected your most recent binary in iTunes Connect.
>
> I add two additional reasons for completeness (which occur very rarely)
>   1. The price tier of the items is 80+ ($500+)
>   2. The test device is jailbroken.
>
> There is also a third reason, which stems from changes made to the sandbox environment, where the simple solution is to clear the application and all provisioning profiles, and reset the device. The instructions follow
>   1. Delete the application.
>   2. Enter the Settings application -> General->Profiles - delete all provisioning profiles
>   3. press and hold down both the application and sleep buttons until the Apple logo appears - (about 10 seconds)
>   4. After the iOS device restarts, install the application and provisioning profile and retest.
>
> Lets assume that resetting the iOS device has no effect. In that case, one of the reasons listed in the FAQ is true.
>
> Regarding the financial requirements, ALL contracts must be complete - there can be no pending items.
>   The next thing to try is to re-download the provisioning profile - in some cases, the development certificate can be changed without your knowledge. Normally, you will be notified, but sometimes, the notification is delayed.
>
> It could be that the binary was uploaded to iTunesConnect, and the current state in iTunesConnect is - rejected. First, you should know, that there is no requirement to upload the binary to iTunesConnect. There is a lingering misperception, that the binary must be uploaded in order to test an in app purchase application. This is false and complicates the test process. If, however, this is true in your case, the solution is to change the application state on iTunesConnect. IF and only IF, the binary has been previously uploaded, and the current state is rejected, then follow these instructions.
>
> Upload a version of the application to iTunesConnect to force the state to change to "pending review". The App Store will take a day (more likely several) before the application is reviewed. In the meantime, you can test the app. Assuming you find that there is still work to do, you will self "reject" the app, make the changes and start the cycle over. At some point the application will be ready and you will leave it for review.