# Cannot connect to the iTunes Store UIStorekit Error in InAppPurchase test

Tags: iphone, ios, in-app-purchase

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [iPhone In-App Purchase Store Kit error -1003 “Cannot connect to iTunes Store”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1717700/iphone-in-app-purchase-store-kit-error-1003-cannot-connect-to-itunes-store)

I am trying to test an iOS purchase, and I suddenly startp getting an error from UIStoreKit: "Cannot connect to the iTunes Store" on my test device whenever I try to make a purchase.

What can I  do to eliminate this error and fix my ability to test?

Answer (score 0):

If u get this Error , try to login with Actual iTunes account(not test account which is used to test inAppPurchase) and log out from your device and then try  InAppPurchase.

If it still says the same Error 
then reset your network settings in your  device.

Settings >> General >> Reset >> Rest Network Settings

It takes few minutes to reset (it`ll restarts your device)

its worked for me....!