# add inApp functionality - how much effort is it

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase

I have developed an app which provides analysis functionality for certain devices. I am thinking about an approach where the basic version only allows limited analysis and one may buy additional functionality through inApp. At maximum 2 inApp addons.

Since I have never done inApp so far I would like to ask how much effort is it to add inApp including the testing/setting up test purchases etc to a finished app. Assuming that the purchasable addon structures are already prepared.

Also, while we are at it, what is the experience with inApp in these cases (not games!) if there is any. Let's say the full version would cost $70 while the most basic costs $10. Is it better to just offer the full version or do the inApp approach? What is your experience?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a tough question to answer, because it depends a lot on how much/what kind of experience you have, and how the in-app experience is designed. My experience is that it's not trivial, the StoreKit API is one of the less intuitive to work with, the iTunes configuration and approval process is complicated and unintuitive, and [testing is a PITA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1717700/iphone-in-app-purchase-store-kit-error-1003-cannot-connect-to-itunes-store/6552736#6552736).

So most of the overhead is in getting your head around how everything works and how to test. But the actual code to implement the StoreKit API isn't complicated, and there's some [good boilerplate code](http://troybrant.net/blog/2010/01/in-app-purchases-a-full-walkthrough/) out there you can use to start with.

Since the tough part is doing it the first time, it's a lot easier the second time you do it, though testing is always a pain. I'd give yourself a solid week to develop and test it the first time, and assume you'll spend some time after that tweaking the flow.

One last thing--if you decide to [verify store receipts on your own server](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/VerifyingStoreReceipts/VerifyingStoreReceipts.html), assume another few days at least to develop, integrate, and test that.

Comment: this seems to be quite alot - many thanks for the detailed answer!