# IAP Works in one project, yet I get Code=0 "Cannot connect to iTunes Store" in another project

Tags: iphone, objective-c, in-app-purchase

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [iPhone In-App Purchase Store Kit error -1003 “Cannot connect to iTunes Store”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1717700/iphone-in-app-purchase-store-kit-error-1003-cannot-connect-to-itunes-store)

I have a project in which I am getting the infamous In-App Purchase `Code=0 "Cannot connect to iTunes Store"` error, which I understand to be a generic error. I've been working on fixing this - going through the zillions of SO questions about this, with absolutely no luck.

I then downloaded am IAP tutorial project from [here](http://xcodenoobies.blogspot.com/2012/04/implementing-inapp-purchase-in-xcode.html) and plugged in my product identifiers, and it worked perfectly!

I copied the code **exactly** from the working tutorial project to my original project, and the original project (now with the new code from the tutorial) still `"Cannot connect to iTunes Store"`.

Both projects have the same bundle identifiers, and both projects are signed with the same provisioning profile. (And yes, I deleted and cleaned in between deploying each project to my device).

Does anyone have any clue how to debug this? I am at a complete loss here.

Comment: I want to know are you testing on same device, in which IAP was working fine?

Comment: Yes, same device. But I just figured it out. So annoying Apple! I'll post my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was solved by the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1717700/iphone-in-app-purchase-store-kit-error-1003-cannot-connect-to-itunes-store/7541204#7541204)

How is this even an issue? Sheeesh! But at least that fixed it for me.

Comment: Please mark this as the correct answer if your problem has been solved.  No need to have this wind up in the unanswered queue.