# Can I make real IAP purchases from AdHoc build?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, adhoc

I have an approved `iOS` application in `AppStore`. There are few approved in-app purchases.

**Question:** Can I make a real purchase from AdHoc version of my app?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you cannot test a real in-app purchases through sandbox while the application is in adhoc. Real purchase can only be done if and only if the app is downloaded from the appstore. But if it is working fine in the sandbox testing, it is bound to work exactly fine in the real enviornment.

Comment: Hi Ali, thank you for your feedback. Do you know what is expected to happen when I try to use real iTunes account to buy a product in AdHoc app? What kind of error I should see? (So far, I see "Cannot connect to iTunes" with error code 0).

Comment: No, it should work in Adhoc exactly how it would work in the real app. The in-app purchases should work if you have entered the condition for running it in adhoc and the in-app should be purchased with the only difference that money will not be taken off from your itunes account.
If it is giving you the error "Cannot connect to itunes", you should read this: 

`http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1717700/iphone-in-app-purchase-store-kit-error-1003-cannot-connect-to-itunes-store?rq=1`

Comment: To make it clear: can I make IAP purchases with real iTunes account in AdHoc app? (and please, tell me when is sandbox in this case? we use server receipt verification, is it that sandbox you are talking about)?

Comment: You need a test account to do this, it is mandatory. Real account does not work while you are testing your application. Real itunes account work only when the app is in store.

Comment: Sandbox is just your testing mode, that is the state while your are testing your adhoc app installed in your mobile via xcode or .apk

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52527/discussion-between-max-b-and-khawar-ali)