# Testing In App Purchases - Cannot Connect to iTunes Store

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, in-app-purchase

I'm returning to some code I wrote in 2012. Back then, I had created a wrapper for the StoreKit framework that also did receipt validation using the sandbox URL for iTunes.

Since it's been so long, I looked through the StoreKit docs and AFAIK, nothing's changed.

For some reason, I can't test my In App Purchases anymore because I get the above error (Cannot Connect to iTunes Store) and the sandbox servers seem to be down (http://sandbox.itunes.apple.com/).

It's been down for the past 2 days. Is this normal? Or has the process for testing changed since when I first wrote this code?

Comment: No it's work. Maybe you should create test user in account of app you are developed.

Comment: But how come this link - http://sandbox.itunes.apple.com/ says 'service unavailable'.

Answer (score 0):

In most of the cases like this, if you test it out in simulator (iOS 6/7/8) - you will get more about the error using `[error localizedDescription]`.

The reasons can be numerous - most of the time it is caused by nonsandbox user. But it can be caused by reasons like app ID not matching that on itunes connect server too.

Comment: I get an error domain 0 with the message "Cannot connect to iTunes Store". Also, if you visit - http://sandbox.itunes.apple.com/ it seems to be down. I even made sure my app ID was matching the live app during testing.

Comment: You may get better options from this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1717700/iphone-in-app-purchase-store-kit-error-1003-cannot-connect-to-itunes-store?rq=1

Comment: Thanks for the link, Nirav. Unfortunately, I can confirm that it is connecting to the sandbox servers.